SAP MATERIALLONGTEXT Control Locked After Calling BAPI_MATERIAL_SAVEDATA from C#
I have an C# program that calls BAPI_MATERIAL_SAVEDATA to create or update MATERIALLONGTEXT, and it works fine.
However, after updating the data from the C# program, the input field for MATERIALLONGTEXT in MM02 becomes disabled. I can still update the data by clicking the Edit button, but not directly in the field.
Interestingly, when I call BAPI_MATERIAL_SAVEDATA from SE80 with the same input data, the field is not disabled.
Has anyone encountered this issue before or knows how to resolve it?
Best Regards

Obviously, there is something different either in the BAPI parameters or the context (e.g. SAP login user, SAP GUI connected or not) between C# and SE80, so you need to compare them. Based on the little information given, only you can reproduce and compare.
